# Creating linking an a href tag to a specific data cell

Tags: html

Hello I am trying to create a link to information in a table. I tried doing something like this with a href and giving the table cell a certain id...it didn't work.

Is it possible to create a link to specific row of data in a table?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain HTML validation you'd want to put an anchor inside a cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qSZ77/

```
<a href="#my-anchor">My anchor</a>

<table>
    ...
    <tr>
        <td><a name="my-anchor"></a>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```